# Is it possible to make a Firefox Tab semi-transparent?

Tags: firefox

There are methods for making a firefox window semi-transparent so that other windows will show up in the background, but is it possible to make a tab semi-transparent so that another tab could show in the background?

Comment: What OS do you use, and if Linux, what window manager do you use?

Comment: I would prefer a cross platform solution, but I am open to any solution in Windows or Linux platform. I use Gnome with Compiz in Linux, but also I am open to using KDE.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give you a definitive yes or no answer, but I believe behavior like that would have to be implemented by Firefox itself, since Firefox acts like the "window manager" for its tabs. If it's not supported by the browser, I don't believe there's anything the underlying window manager can do to create that behavior.

You could try looking for a Firefox addon that does this. If it's possible, somebody's probably written it. I did a Google search for `firefox transparent tab` but I didn't notice anything that does what you want (then again, I only looked at a few of the top results, so feel free to examine the search yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://userstyles.org/ there are a number of styles that make firefox transparent. One option is http://userstyles.org/styles/3874 but you can search for others.

The style can be applied either by adding the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) addon or, in a lot of cases, you can enter the code directly into userchrome.css.

Answer (score 0):

There is no a good way to have firefox transparent. transset-df on linux can make something like that, but the complete windows goes transparent, that includes letters too. I don't know if transset-df works with xcompmgr o composite, perhaps no.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Can you provide more information as to how transset-df would fit Swamplords needs?